# Create a dynamic property in C#

Tags: c#, razor

In razor view engine, you can add property (I'm not sure if they are called properties) to the `Page` object. How can I create an object that behaves like `Page`? Here's the sample code in Razor C#:

```
Page.AProperty = "Hi";
Page.AnotherProperty = 1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx):

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

obj.Pro1 = 1;
obj.Pro2 = "Hi";
```

Comment: Wow! How is that possible? Can I create my own class like ExpandoObject or is it built into the .NET Framework?

Comment: @dpp: it is built-in class in .NET

Comment: I tried this and it's working fine. I can add properties, I was surprised though that I received and error accessing property which was not set `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'SomeProperty'`. This doesn't happen in object `Page`. This should remain as the correct answer since it addressed the question.

Comment: @dpp: What is your expectation in the case which property is not set?

Comment: No error, it should return null. It's not impossible since the `WebPageBase.Page` of WebMatrix can do it. I'm curious of what this `Page` is made of.

Comment: @dpp: You can try [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying it now. It seems like I need to override the `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` of the class to prevent exception. Also, I cannot instantiate the class directly due to its protection level.

Comment: @dpp: yes, it's abstract class, you can follow the example

Comment: Seen it... the sample does not suppress the error. I'll find methods to override.

Comment: I just need to return true in `TryGetMember` regardless of the result.